# How can I draw a shape in CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: Chat UI]

initially in my chat application the reply on a chat is hidden and shows only count on the red box when user clicks on red button it shows all the reply by other users and in the end a input box for reply, all inside the blue box. How I can draw this shape using CSS.

Comment: give us some html and basic CSS to start with to see what you tried and where you get stucked . it can be done

Comment: [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) is a good demonstration on css3 shapes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SGTBX/).

Spend all of your time playing with the CSS in the upper right hand corner, and watch what happens.

CSS

```
.holder {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 0px solid black;
}
.upper {
    height: 30%;
    border: 0px solid red;
}
.littleblue {
    height: 100%;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    float: right;
}
.littlered {
    width: 90%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.lower {
    height: 70%;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
    border: 0px solid green;
}
```

Comment: @Devnegikec if this truly saved your day perhaps consider marking it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

basicly with a form and 2 fielset :

```
<div>
  <form>
    <fieldset class="right">
      <button>button</button>
        </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
div {
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
}
fieldset {
    background:blue;
  clear : right;
  height:100px;  /* remove height once content in */
  border:none;
    border-radius:1em  0 1em 1em;
}
.right {
  float:right;
  border-radius:1em  1em 0 0;
  height:50px;/* remove height once content in */
  position:relative;/* to set pseudo element where you want */
}
.right:after{
  content:'';
  height:2em;/* use he twice value and units used for radius */
  width:2em;
  position:absolute;
  left:-2em;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:2em;
  box-shadow: 23px 23px 0 10px blue;/* drop shadow to draw inside round corner */
  z-index:-1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vIgon/